# Terminology for a weaked vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology, convex-analysis, semigroups

Let $S$ be a semigroup on which acts $\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$.
Does this structure has a name?

For example $S$ can be the set of convex bodies in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Minkowsky sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the semigroup to be commutative (as it is for Minkowski sum), such an object is called a [convex cone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone).

*Added*: When if it's not naturally sitting in a vector space, one can avoid confusion by calling the object an *abstract* convex cone. For example, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_function) talks about

> (abstract) convex cone of nonempty compact convex sets

Comment: Ok, that seems to me true. A convex cone lives in a vector space, so we need to show that the semigroup $S$ (which we assume commutative) is a subset of a group $G$. I think this is true but I don't have reference for that. Do you?
I think we can construct a group $G$ from $S$ by adding an identity element, inverse elements and quotient it by some equivalence relation in order to kill the elements we have in doble (maybe $S$ has already an identity elements and some inverse elements).

Comment: ok, my previous construction fails actually. The sum of an element of $S$ and an "inverse" element is not defined in general with this construction. The answer is that $G$ is the so called [group of fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup#Group_of_fractions) of $S$.

Comment: @GillesBonnet I think it's acceptable to use the term *convex cone* in a more general way, for objects that are not naturally subsets of a vector space. See my addendum to the answer.